# MYSQL Window Function Frame Specification / Sliding Windows

Tags: mysql, sliding-window

I am trying to use sliding windows to calculate running total of the 'Request_Amount' within each region. Copied the format from MYSQL reference manual (`https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-frames.html`).

Getting an error about:

```
SUM(val) OVER (PARTITION BY subject ORDER BY time
                ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    AS running_total,
```

I tried using the function:

```
SELECT Expected_Award
,Quarter
,Region
,Project
,Request_Amount AS Amt
,SUM(Request_Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY Region ORDER BY Expected_Award
                        ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
           AS running_total
FROM quarterly_data
ORDER BY Expected_Award, Region, Quarter;
```

Expected:

```
Expected_Award  Quarter Region  Project       Amt       running_total
2022-10-07  2023Q1  CENTRAL CE53200     9       9
2022-11-11  2023Q1  CENTRAL CE44986     42      51
2023-06-28  2023Q3  CENTRAL CE99081     45      96
2023-07-04  2023Q4  CENTRAL CE06733     8       104
2023-08-16  2023Q4  CENTRAL CE89722     24      128
2023-08-20  2023Q4  CENTRAL CE34836     36      164
2023-09-28  2023Q4  CENTRAL CE41919     28      192
2022-10-26  2023Q1  SOUTH   SO58587     41      41
2022-11-27  2023Q1  SOUTH   SO06065     14      55
2022-12-31  2023Q1  SOUTH   SO51694     10      65
2023-02-02  2023Q2  SOUTH   SO49109     26      91
2023-09-29  2023Q4  SOUTH   SO49764     11      102
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, we also need to see the error message or the output you are getting with the incorrect results so that someone can compare them.

Comment: Also please run the query `SELECT VERSION();` and report what it returns.

Comment: Window functions require MySQL 8.x. If you're using 5.x this won't work.

Comment: Sliding window should use the `LAG()` window function. `UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` is cumulative sum, not sliding window.